# Cost Benefit Analysis of Pre-screening Widgets for Faults before they Fail

Tags: r, modeling, predictive-models, model-selection, stata

I want to build a model that determines whether to pre-screen my widgets for defects.  If I do pre-screen, it costs a fixed amount per check and I resolve the problem 100% of the time.  If I don't pre-screen, its cost will be the cost of fixing the problem, plus the cost of materials for expired inventory.  I have a whole bunch of variables that impact whether a defect will occur in each particular widget, but if it does occur and I didn't pre-screen it, it will definitely result in a fixed repair cost and a variable expired inventory cost based on cost of materials.  For each widget, I need to know if the expected cost of the defect exceeds or is less than the cost of pre-screening.

Things I know:

- A - Cost of pre-screening
- B - Model to Predict Whether it will fail - based on test data - of ones
  it says it won't have a defect, it is right 98.5% of the time (false negatives).
- C -Model to Predict expected cost of Raw Materials for each widget produced
- D - % of repairs that will be successful and result in no expired inventory cost
- E - Fixed Cost of Repairs

Therefore, I should screen if:

A - B*(E+C*D) > 0

I have all of these pieces, but I don't know how to build this into a model.

Anyone with R or Stata skills, I would appreciate being pointed in the direction of a good package to use for building this model.

Comment: Please let me know if this answered your question or if you have any further concerns.

Answer (score 1):

Considering my predilection for `R`, I am going to do something unlikely: [I would advise you not to use `R` or any other program](http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-best-code-is-no-code-at-all/).  If you agree to the principle that the production should be done correctly, I think you would agree with the principle that determining the inspection criteria and the inspection itself should be as simple as possible (but you can call it a "decision tree" to justify your title):

**Question 1: Is the supply of your part stable?**

**A1 == NO.** Considering a type of widget: *if* the supply of this widget is [not in a state of control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_process_control#Excessive_variation), strongly consider 100% inspection (Deming, 1986).  **DONE.**

**A1 == YES.**  OK. . .

**Question 2: Does the cost of testing outweigh the cost of not testing?**

*If* the supply of this part is in [control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_process_control#Stable_process), you can adopt an [all-or-nothing testing strategy (Deming, 1986), given](http://asq.org/qic/display-item/?item=5499):

```
p   = [historic] average percent defective [from] incoming lots of parts 
      (e.g. received 100 widgets Friday, 3 defective; p = 3%).  
      Remember: stable process exists! 
k   = cost to inspect one part
l   = cost to dismantle, repair, reassemble, and test an assembly that 
      fails because a defective part was put into the production line.
k/l = break even quality, or break-even point (always between 0 and 1)
```

**A2 == NO.** *If* `p > k/l` *inspect 100%.*  You will save money with each inspection by preventing expensive mistakes further down the production line.  **DONE.**

**A2 == YES.** *If* `p < k/l` *inspect 0%.*  You will lose money with each inspection by spending valuable time inspecting parts that are most likely acceptable.  **DONE.**

The statistical proof of this is "exceedingly simple," but involves a chart which I might attempt to reproduce later if I'm feeling ambitious.  I would encourage you to find a copy of the text which I created this answer from:

> *Deming, W. E.* (1986). Out of the Crisis (Ch 15). Cambridge, MA: MIT 
>   Center for Advanced Engineering Study.